# Zend_Log_Formatter_Simple undefined Magento 1.7

Tags: magento-1.7, zend-framework

I am getting this error when trying to place order through credit card in magento 1.7 CE ( We are using HHVM )

> error
>
> Fatal error: Class undefined: Zend_Log_Formatter_Simple in
>   ./app/Mage.php on line 833

Comment: Check if the file in lib/Zend/Log/Formatter/Simple.php is present.

Comment: It is already there, happens only when placing order using credit card.

Comment: I think it's hard to tell without a backtrace. Could you please update your question? Also: have a look where/how the Zend_Log_Formatter_Simple in your credit card extension (?). Which credit card payment method is it?

Comment: I am using HHVM updating it to the latest version fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Updating to the latest version of HHVM to 3.13.1 fixed the issue.

Comment: Great it worked for you. Next time you ask a question here it would be great to add "details" like this to your question ;)